# Stuck with this parametric equation of a hyperbola - involving multiplication of parameters, and perpendicular lines.

Tags: graphing-functions, proof-explanation, parametric

I'm quite lost solving the below problem.

> **P**, **Q**, **R** and **S** are four points on the hyperbola $x = ct$, $y = \frac{c}{t}$ with parameters **p**, **q**, **r**, and **s** respectiveley. Prove that, if the chord **PQ** is perpendicular to the chord **RS**, then $pqrs = -1$.

I know that $\frac{dy}{dx} = {\frac{dy}{dt}} / \frac{dx}{dt}$, but don't see how that fits into the picture, except that *when multiplying the gradient of two perpendicular lines, the result is $-1$.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Think about the vectors $PQ=P-Q$ and $RS=R-S$.

**Answer:** We have that $P=(cp,\frac cp)$, $Q=(cq,\frac cq)$, $R=(cr,\frac cr)$ and $S=(cs,\frac cs)$. Then
$$PQ=(cp-cq, \frac cp - \frac cq)=
(c(p-q), c\frac{q-p}{pq})$$ and
$$RS=(cr-cs, \frac cr - \frac cs)=
(c(r-s), c\frac{s-r}{rs}).$$
Since $PQ\perp RS$, we have that $PQ\cdot RS=0$, i.e.
$$c^2(p-q)(r-s)+c^2\frac{q-p}{pq}\frac{s-r}{rs}=c^2(p-q)(r-s)(1+\frac{1}{pqrs})=0.$$
Since $c\neq 0$, $p\neq q $ and $r\neq s$, it follows that
$$1+\frac{1}{pqrs}=0,$$
that is, $$pqrs=-1.$$

Comment: Almost makes sense: when expanding $c^2(p - q)(r - s)(1 + \frac{1}{pqrs})$ would you not get $c^2 \frac{(q - p)(s - r)}{pqrs}$ in the latter part instead of  $c^2\frac{(p - q)(r - s)}{pqrs}$ ?

Comment: It's because $(q-p)(s-r)=(-1)(p-q)(-1)(r-s)=(p-q)(r-s)$.